# Using python requests module to create an authenticated session in Github

Tags: python, rest, github, python-requests

My goal to create an authenticated session in github so I can use the advanced search (which limits functionality to non-authenticated users).  Currently I am getting a webpage response from the post request of "What? Your browser did something unexpected. Please contact us if the problem persists."

Here is the code I am using to try to accomplish my task.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

s = requests.Session()
payload = (username, password)
_ = s.get('https://www.github.com/login')
p = s.post('https://www.github.com/login', auth=payload)

url = "https://github.com/search?l=&p=0&q=language%3APython+extension%3A.py+sklearn&ref=advsearch&type=Code"
r = s.get(url, auth=payload)
text = r.text
tree = html.fromstring(text)
```

Is what I'm trying possible? I would prefer to not use the github v3 api since it is rate limited and I wanted to do more of my own scraping of the advanced search.  Thanks.

Comment: I assume you would need OAuth login, but I could be wrong

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check that out.

Comment: You're trying to use HTTP Basic authentication, but GitHub uses a form-based login mechanism. You would need to inspect the login page to determine what endpoint to which you should `POST` a response with the necessary fields (which may include static fields including in the login form itself).

Comment: The [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) may be useful

Comment: Read [GitHub OAuth 2 Tutorial](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/github.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, github uses post data for authentication so you should have your creds in the [`data`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) parameter.
The elements you have to submit are `'login'`, `'password'`, and `'authenticity_token'`. The value of `'authenticity_token'` is dynamic, but you can scrape it from `'/login'`.
Finally submit `data` to `/session` and you should have an authenticated session.

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.github.com/login')
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
data = {i.get('name'):i.get('value') for i in tree.cssselect('input')}
data['login'] = username
data['password'] = password
r = s.post('https://github.com/session', data=data)
```