# How to use basic authentication to create OAuth Token while working with GitHub APIs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, github-api, django-2.1

I'm working on a django project and I'm trying to implement Github login using username and password.

Here's the content of my `views.py` file:

```
@login_required
def github_access_via_username(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GitHubUserPassAuthForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

            payload = {
                "scopes" : [
                    "repo", "admin:org", "admin:public_key", "admin:repo_hook", "admin:org_hook",
                    "gist", "notifications", "user", "delete_repo", "write:discussion", "admin:gpg_key",
                ],
                "note" : "Permissions",
            }
            response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/authorizations', params=payload, auth=(username, password))
            #json_response = response.json()
            #access_token = json_response['token']
            #user = Github(access_token)
            return HttpResponse(response.status_code)
    else:
        form = GitHubUserPassAuthForm()
    return render(request, 'core/github_login.html', {'form':form})
```

Here's the output of `print(reponse)`

```
{'message': 'Problems parsing JSON', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization'}
[23/Sep/2018 19:55:42] "POST /core/github_access_via_username/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5020
```

I wasn't getting anything so I decided to return the `status_code`, and it returned a `400`. I'm stuck. Any eye opener please?

Comment: @stovfl Done! Please check it out

Comment: Message from github says:problems parsing json. Maybe try ˋjson.dumps(payload)ˋ to encode the dict to json explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python requests module to create an authenticated session in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046327/using-python-requests-module-to-create-an-authenticated-session-in-github)

Comment: Related: [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) and [python-oauth2](https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2)

Comment: @klaas I tried that already (after I posted the question), but response['message'] said `Validation Falied`

Comment: @stovfl That question is different from mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! According to the documentation at [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#get-or-create-an-authorization-for-a-specific-app), you need your client id and client secret keys to get or create new authorizations. So I modified the `payload` dict and `response` variable as follows:

```
...
payload = {
    ...            
    "client_secret" : settings.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
}
response = requests.put('https://api.github.com/authorizations/clients/{}'.format(settings.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID), auth=(username, password), data=json.dumps(payload))
...
```

...and that worked!